# Add wait in ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an `ng-repeat` block where I am creating few elements The data in the elements is comming from an ajax request which takes a little time. Also in the same block I have used a filter to filterout some unwanted data. For filtering I am looping through the list of data comming from the ajax request. But it tells that that the list is not defined.

All I can think of is thisi is due to the latency in the ajax request. Below is my code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | doFilter: pricemin" >
    <div><img src="images/nopreview.png" class="item-preview"/></div>
    <div>{{item.NAME}}</div>
    <div>{{item.PRICE}}{{item.CURRENCY}}</div>
    <div>{{item.DESCRIPTION}}</div>
    <div><button ng-click="addToCart(item)">Add To Cart</button></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
app.filter('doFilter', function(){

return function(items, pricemin){
    var minPrice = [], maxPrice = [];        
    for (var i =0; i < items.length; i++){
        if (pricemin != "") {
            if(pricemin <= items[i].PRICE)
                minPrice.push(items[i]);
        }
    }
    return minPrice;
};});
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to add a "wait" just initialize the array within your controller this way your UI will continue to function even if the ajax call were to fail, and no data would get added to the array.

In your controller do the following:

```
$scope.items = [];
```

Comment: I used your suggestion and its working, but when I did the following without creating the `items` variable in the controller, it worked: `for (var i in items){}`. This way I was not accessing the length property of the `items` variable. Can you you please give me some suggestion on this?

Comment: JavaScript will allow you to iterate over an object, not just arrays. So in this case it was attempting to iterate over the properties of $scope.items in which case there were none.